# Get type of property in deserializer (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I'm looking for a way to deserialize a subclass using a deserializer registered using the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on the abstract super class. If there are better options I'm happy to adapt these options – but I'm not aware of any solution to this problem at the moment.

The core problem is: There is an abstract super class `A`:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SerializerForA.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DeserializerForA.class)
public abstract class A {
  private String value;

  protected A(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  ...
}
```

(The annotations are my attempt to do custom deserialization – maybe it's the wrong approach).

There are some derived classes, and `A` doesn't know any of the derived classes. Think about `A` is part of a framework and the derived classes are client code using the framework. Here are two derived classes:

```
public class B extends A {
  public B(String value) {
    super(value);
  }
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class C extends A {
  public C(String value) {
    super(value);
  }
  ...
}
```

These derived classes are used in a "container" class, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass {
  private B b;
  private C c;

  ...
}
```

And the corresponding JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "b": "value_of_b",
  "c": "value_of_c"
}
```

Writing a serializer is relatively simple:

```
public class SerializerForA extends JsonSerializer<A> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(A obj, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeString(obj.getValue());
  }
}
```

The deserializer would look like this:

```
public class DeserializerForA extends JsonDeserializer<A> {
  @Override
  public A deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    A result = ???
    return result;
  }
}
```

**But how does the deserializer know, which type the resulting object has? Is it possible to get the class name from one of the parameters (e.g. `DeserializationContext`)?**

There are some ways the code can be changed, if it helps. For example, a setter can be used for the `value` field, instead of the constructor, but I would prefer a constructor, or some factory method (`public static A getInstance(String value) { ... }`).

---

**Edit (1)** The deserializer should be called without any specific code automatically by the `ObjectMapper`, like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

That means, Jackson knows the type of the container class. It also knows the type of the properties `a` and `b`.
The reason to use a custom deserializer is that I need to have control over the instance creation process (basically, I want to reuse the same instance of each object for the same value – similar to an enum).

---

**Edit (2)** Changing the JSON structure is not an option. But I don't think it should be necessary. If I didn't need to have control over instance creation, the whole implementation would just work out of the box. Additional type information in the JSON should not be necessary.

---

**Edit (3)** The purpose of all of this is to implement a framework that can be used by application to create typesafe objects that are stored as JSON. Normally, I would use a Java `enum` for this purpose, but it is possible, that clients need to read JSON documents that are created by a new version of the framework (with new values), but the client didn't update the framework version yet.

Example:

There is a class called `Currency`:

```
public class Currency extends A {
  public static final Currency EUR = new Currency("EUR");
}
```

It is used like this:

```
public class Transaction {
  private Currency currency;
  private double amount;
}
```

The JSON would look like this:

```
{
  "currency": "EUR",
  "amount": 24.34
}
```

Now a new currency is added:

```
public class Currency extends A {
  public static final Currency EUR = new Currency("EUR");
  public static final Currency USD = new Currency("USD");
}
```

Clients with the new framework can produce the following JSON:

```
{
  "currency": "USD",
  "amount": 48.93,
}
```

One client didn't update to the new framework version. This client should be able to read the JSON without crashing.

Comment: Can you show how the deserialization happens? I mean, how does your deserializer end up called?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ – I have updated the question with a simple ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, the `ObjectMapper` is provided with an instance of `MyClass` containing one `B` and one `C`.

Jackson will call the `JsonDeserializer<A>` both for `B` and `C` providing the string `"value_of_b"` / `"value_of_c"` (because by reflection, it will know that `B` and `C` are instances of `A` and that's the only deserializer available in the context).

Considering that in the Jackson deserializer you are in a static context (you don't have any concrete instance of `A` in there, you're just deserializing some string text with information that allows you to create a new instance of `MyClass` that looks like the serialized instance that they provided you with), then I think the only option you have is to create a factory method somewhere in your code as you guessed (I'd create it directly in the `A` class):

```
public static A getInstance(String value) {
    ...
}
```

and then inside the deserializer, simply instantiate it from that independently on whether the serialized instance was a `B` or a `C` (cause at the end of the day, you only know `A` so you can't handle anything else):

```
public final class ADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<A> {
    @Override
    public A deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String value = jsonParser.getText();
        return A.getInstance(value);
    }
}
```

So basically each implementation will provide you with the `String value` that you need to create an `A`, and of course you will have to create a concrete basic implementation of `A` on your side in order to instantiate it (because you don't know what the other implementations are, and because you need it to be concrete to create an instance).

Comment: Thanks, Matteo NNZ – but the deserializer should not create an instance of `A`, but of `B` or `C`. Technically, the ObjectMapper should know at that point, that it is trying to create an instance of type `B` or `C`. It would be great, if that type information would be accessible to the deserializer.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen imagine that you could. How would you use it after deserialization? You don't know them. You only know A, you would only use methods of A. So what's the point of creating B or C if they're just A at your eyes? If there is a point, then I guess is the caller who should provide you with the concrete factory implementations (the thing you want to avoid basically)

Comment: Yeah, the deserializer would invoke a lot of reflection magic. Let's say, `A`has a private field `value`. Then it would create a new instance `A a = type.newInstance(); // type is B.class` and then `valueField.set(a, theValue);`. Then Jackson could set the created object to `b` of the container class.

Comment: So in that case, I simply think it's not you who should provide a deserializer. I surely miss more use case context but as well as you provide the abstract class and they provide the concrete implementations, then the same should happen with the concrete deserializers. I really don't know how you could create an instance of B if you're by design not supposed to know what B is

Comment: The type hierarchy of `A` is intended to replace some "extensible" enums. So, all subclasses of `A` are very simple and just represent values. `B` can be instantiated by the deserializer without explicitly knowing the type, and once created it knows that the `value` needs to be set. The problem why I can't use _real_ enums is, that all of this will be used in a library with predefined instances (say: `class B extends A { public static final B one = new B("one"); public static final B two = new B("two"); etc. }`). It is possible, that a JSON document also contains `three` as a value for `B`.

Comment: Ok let's turn the question differently. Why do you need to deserialize them? What do you want to do exactly? I'm asking that because for me, if you don't know (and are not supposed to) what is B or C, then there is no point in having more than the actual value contained in B or C under the form of A. If they're asking you to deserialize them just to use them on your side, you don't need to know. But apparently you do need, so please can you share why you need to know that it was a B rather than a C?

Comment: I updated the question with a more realistic example; does that make the intention more clear?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen thanks, it's better, but still unclear. If the client creates a class Currency and initializes it with a different string each time, they'll build their own collection of currencies (which is always the same object, with a different value). Another client may use the same A to create a Token, another one to create an EmployeeId, etc. and they would all have one string value. Now the point is: whether it's a Currency, or a Token, or an EmployeeId... after you deserialize it, what do you need to do with that value? Store it somewhere? Log it? What else?

Comment: that is an excellent question! That particular client may ignore or just log it. Other clients may call another service (e.g. for conversion) or do other things. A simple String would be probably sufficient for all clients, but I try to keep type safety as much as possible. Also, it would avoid to build two versions of the container class (one with Strings only and one typesafe).

Comment: @MoritzPetersen given the call chain that you describe: Client calls the ObjectMapper with a Transaction class and a string which represents this transaction to get deserialized. The object mapper will call your deserializer in order to build the instance of Currency that the client is asking to deserialize. However, you don't know what a currency is, you just know what A is. So it doesn't make sense to me that it's you deserializing Currency, it should be the client. You don't know what Currency is, it shouldn't be you deserializing it unless you don't want to just retrieve the underlying A

Comment: I can follow your arguments, but I disagree. See: Jackson itself is a framework and doesn't know anything about the classes that it instantiates. The same level of abstraction is what I want to achieve with this Deserializer.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I see your point, but look at Jackson how it works. It gets the class, it reflects over all the fields/methods, you're obliged to specify a JsonConstructor if the constructor is ambiguous, to annotate your fields to help reflection etc. Jackson manages to do that because it intensively uses Reflection. If you want to do the same, either you gain access to private fields of the ObjectMapper (such as the class you're parsing), or you re-code your own Jackson yourself, or a mix of the two :)

Comment: P.s. since you mention it, when in Jackson you want to deserialize an object that doesn't follow standard Java class (that can be done by reflection), you're forced to define your own JsonDeserializer. Same goes here, your "currency" (or whatever implementation of A) doesn't follow a standard reflection that you can do on your own without them providing you with the right deserializer.

Comment: My assumption was, that I define the "default behavior" for all classes extending `A` – which in my case is simple. And I would also assume that Jackson already knows the type that should be created, but doesn't know how to do it. That's why I thougt it could be implemented somehow. My current solution is to use factory methods on each derived class. It's not too pretty, but also quite ok, especially because I don't need to implement a lot of nasty reflection stuff. But maybe I dig a bit deeper into the Jackson code an provide a patch :-)

Comment: @MoritzPetersen when you're asked to deserialize Currency from a Json string of text, you have the same information that Jackson has. And Jackson does that by loading the class from the class loader and reflecting on it (with or without help of annotations, depending on how simple the class is). But it has to do that, it has no other choice. And I guess you don't have either if you want to provide the same functionality without a factory provided by the client. Anyway, it's a nice problem to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include some information during the serialization in the json. There are two ways to achieve that.

First is to enable default typing. This will add class names to your json. It will look like this:

```
{
  "a": [
    "A",
    {
      "value": "a"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    "B",
    {
      "value": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can enable it on `ObjectMapper` by calling `activateDefaultTyping(ptv, DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE)`

Second one is to add per-class annotations. You can achieve that by adding those annotations to your abstract class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = A.class, name = "a"), 
  @Type(value = B.class, name = "b") 
})
```

Then the serializer will produce json like this:

```
{
  "a": {
    "type": "a",
    "value": "value_of_a"
  }
  "b": {
    "type": "b",
    "value": "value_of_b"
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't know what classes are B, C etc. because they are implemented outside of his codeline, so he can't use either of the mentioned solutions in his code

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the JSON is not an option. Also, as Matteo NNZ mentioned, the base class doesn't know the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution – that even doesn't need a lot of magic – is to use a factory method and `@JsonCreator`:

The base class is already known, and also the serializer:

```
  @JsonSerialize(using = SerializerForA.class)
  public class A {
    protected String value;

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  public class SerializerForA extends JsonSerializer<A> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException {
      gen.writeString(a.getValue());
    }
  }
```

The inherited classes need to implement a factory method each:

```
  public class B extends A {
    @JsonCreator
    public static B create(String value) {
      B b = new B();
      b.value = value;
      return b;
    }
  }
```

and

```
  public class C extends A {
    @JsonCreator
    public static C create(String value) {
      C c = new C();
      c.value = value;
      return c;
    }
  }
```

Now the following JSON is parsed successfully:

```
{
  "b":"This is B",
  "c":"This is C"
}
```

The obvious downside is, that inherited classes have to implement the factory method. I'd like to avoid that.